# How to Track Connections On a Server Accurately

Tags: linux, apache, google-analytics

I have a dedicated server hosting a website of mine and I have about 10% of my traffic unaccounted for.

The path of the clicks is as follows

**Ads on Facebok ==> My Website**

I have Google Analytics script on My Website (on the bottom) and it should fire off whenever a person lands on the page.

The problems is that if I have **4000 clicks on the Ad** (tracked by Facebook), Google Analytics tells me I have about **3600 people landing on My Website.**

I also invested in real-time tracking software like Clicky and it gives me similar results to Google Analytics. (just in case GA is not accurate)

So I have narrowed it down to 3 scenarios:

1) The Ad clicks aren't being tracked properly by Facebook (I have made sure this is not the problem)

**2)** The page  is taking too long for some people to load and they are hitting the back button before Google Analytics can be triggered.

**3)** Some connection are dropping from the Ad to My Website.

**Can anyone recommend a way I can make sure 2 and 3 aren't happening? and if they are
how would I fix them.**

Comment: Of course it can be that your site is too slow; but also consider the possibility that people may have blocking software installed that prevents GA from working

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make an assumption that you're using Apache. It should be possible to parse the Apache logs to extract connections from unique IP addresses. Hopefully the URL requested by the client will contain some sort of path indicating that it was directed from Facebook.

Link:
[Get unique visitors from apache log file](http://geekpad.ca/blog/post/get-unique-visitors-from-apache-log-file)